# Rails - how do you edit files included by a gem in the asset pipeline?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am new to rails so this is probably a simple question about using the asset pipeline.

In my app, I want to use this jquery plugin: http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/star-rating/

So to do it, I included the following gem in my gemfile: https://github.com/RichGuk/jquery-star-rating-rails

However, I find that the image used for the star ratings is too low resolution and I'd also like to change the style. However, all 3 versions of the stars that are displayed are held in one image so I'd have to play around with the scripts as well to make sure they are configured properly if I make the image for the stars larger.

Back to my question: How do I edit this image file in my application?

I've tried downloading all the files and putting them in my vender directory and editing the file but it did not seem to work.

I know the files are included by the gem but how do make the files visible to edit?

Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So the asset pipeline consists of potentially many directories (assuming you are using gems that inject their own assets into the pipeline).  When an asset is being grabbed in Rails, Rails goes through these directories (in the same order, every time) to find the asset.  When the name of the file is first found, that's it, Rails grabs it and uses that file.

Vendor asset directories are specified after app assets, I believe.  So, if you place the image that you want to change in the app/assets/images folder, you'll essentially be overriding that vendor image in your application with your own image since Rails will search it's own app/assets first.  Obviously, the files need to be named the same.

Comment: A warning about that. A friend of mine was telling me about an odd problem he had with the asset pipeline and files that are named the same as other files in the asset pipeline. (almost impossible to diagnose crashes). If you're using some kind of gem to install the star rating jQuery plugin, perhaps you should remove that gem from your Gemfile, so _your_ copy is the only one around for the asset pipeline to finde.

Answer (score 2):

1. Try adding your star image in your assets path. It seem to
   reference `star.gif` using the `asset_path`
2. I would also try
   overriding the star plugin by creating your own css file.